# Custom linear layout in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have a class extending LinearLayout which receives an array and creates a layout based on 
the array.

Now creating the layout in the OnCreate method of the activity and using setContentView 
to the layout.
I want to know whether I could use it in an XML as I would use LinearLayout or  a similiar way in a layout xml file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use your custom `LinearLayout` in your layout, declare a new element with `<path_to_your_custom_layout_class...`.

Comment: Okay, but how I would pass my boolean multidimesinal array to it?

Comment: do you have the array before runtime?

Comment: @user1050389 The short answer is you can't. You could make your layout styleable and apply a custom attribute, but you can't create a 2D array in XML on Android. So, you're going to have to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

in XML layout:

```
<com.my.package.MyView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:MyStyleable="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.my.package"
    android:id="@id/id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    MyStyleable:attr1="ATTR1 VALUE"
    MyStyleable:attr2="ATTR2 VALUE" />
```

Notice the custom `xml namespace xmlns:MyStyleable` which will contain the custom attributes.

Define the custom attributes in `res/values/attr.xml` :

```
<resources>
    <attr name="attr1" format="string" />
    <attr name="attr2" format="boolean" />
</resources>
```

Then in your custom view class, retrieve the values from XML :

```
String attr1 = a.getString(R.styleable.attr1);
boolean attr2 = a.getBoolean(R.styleable.attr2);
```

Hope it's clear. !

Comment: But I need an array of booleans. not just one attribute

Comment: You can do it with the same method. Create a `String` attribute to pass the name of the boolean array to your custom view !